# What standard shell command can evaluate escaped Unicode in a stream?

Tags: shell, pipe, unicode, escape-characters

I'm looking for a pipeable command that will convert substrings in the form of ‘`\unnnn`’ to the actual characters.

For example:

```
$ echo 'co\u00ebfficient' | what_command
coëfficient
```

Comment: This would be a job for recode, but it doesn't seem to have a `\unnnn` surface.

Comment: What should happen to `foo\ubar` (less than 4 valid digits)? To `\u12345` (U+12345 is the character CUNEIFORM SIGN URU TIMES KI — Unicode doesn't fit in 16 bits)? To `a\\u1234` (how can you have a literal `\u` in the text)?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ printf "co\u00ebfficient\n"
coëfficient
```

Or if you want to do the substitution on a stream:

```
perl -CS -pe 's/\\u(....)/chr hex $1/eg'
```

Comment: I guess you could use command substitution to complete this answer, but so far it doesn't answer the question. I'm looking to _stream_ both from `stdin` and to `stdout`. Also, this command actually returns ‘`co�fficient`’ on my terminal.

Comment: Having said that, the streams will be far to long to be substituted as a shell parameter so I don't think `printf` is an option anyway.

Comment: @JamesHaigh I've edited my answer for a substitution on a stream. BTW, I don't know why the printf solution didn't work on your terminal, but you need to use UTF-8 locales.